# Do Asp.net webform controls have topmost feature like Winforms controls do?

Tags: asp.net, winforms, controls, html, topmost

im wondering if i can make a group of control that will stay on screen even someone on another webpage while my webpage open in another tab,in asp.net.Like winform's topmost feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not do this.

If you're expecting to port a winforms application to webforms feature for feature, you're going to be greatly disappointed. WebForms is still just a thin veneer over the http protocol; one that tends to peel up at the corner.

If you're trying to keep something on top via the web, you can't do that without a plugin, no matter what web platform you use.